# Pyspark -- How to left merge dataframes

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

In Pandas I can merge two dataframes like so:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')


  lkey  value_x rkey  value_y
0  foo        1  foo        5
1  foo        1  foo        8
2  bar        2  bar        6
3  baz        3  baz        7
4  foo        5  foo        5
5  foo        5  foo        8
```

What would the equivalent of this be in pyspark? A left join?

Comment: There are lot of resources on the internet that can be helpful. [this](https://medium.com/@achilleus/https-medium-com-joins-in-apache-spark-part-1-dabbf3475690) or [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply join in pyspark as

```
df = df1.join(df2, df1.lkey==df2.rkey, 'left_outer')
```